# How to group by a second ID column in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following data in excel:

[image]

I want to group this data by the PartnerNumber like shown below:

[image]

I attempted to use PowerQuery by grouping by PartnerNumber, but it returns an error every time. Is there any way to group by the VendorNumber with a comma separating all the values?

I'm ok with doing it via Excel or PowerQuery, either way is fine.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Load data into powerquery  [data .. from table/range [x] have columns]

Click select Partner Number, right click, Group by ..., New Column Name: VendorNumber, and then hit ok to use all other default options

In formula bar, change end of code after **each**, so that

```
each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

becomes

```
each Text.Combine(List.Transform([VendorNumber], Text.From), ", "), type text}})
```

[image]

sample full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"PartnerNumber"}, {{"VendorNumber", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([VendorNumber], Text.From), ", "), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try any one of the approaches as well, since I have mentioned in comment above, sharing in Answer as well, **4 Approaches** -> **2 Approach using Power Query & 2 with Excel Office 365 Formulas**,

Please follow the steps for **Power Query**

• Select any cell of the source,

• From **Data Tab** --> Click **From Table/Range** (`Under Get & Transform Group`)

### Approach One

• Select the First Column i.e. **PartnerNumber** & press `CTRL A`

• From **Transform Tab** --> Click **Data Type** as **Text**

• From **Home Tab** --> Under **Transform Group** --> Click **Group By**,

• **GroupBy PartnerNumber** --> **New Column Name** -> **Vendor_Number** --> **Operation** --> **SUM** --> Press **Ok**

• In the formula bar change the `List.Sum` To `Text.Combine` and press Enter

• From **Home Tab** press **Close & Load Drop down**, from **Import Data** choose either **Existing sheet or New Sheet** and press **Ok**

Here is the `M-Code`

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Partnertbl"]}[Content],
    DataTypeText = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PartnerNumber", type text}, {"VendorNumber", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(DataTypeText, {"PartnerNumber"}, {{"Vendor_Number", each Text.Combine(([VendorNumber]),","), type nullable text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

### Approach Two

• The first two steps remains same as in **Approach One**,

• From **Home Tab** --> Under **Transform Group** --> Click **Group By**,

• **GroupBy PartnerNumber** --> **New Column Name** -> **All** --> **Operation** --> **All Rows** --> Press **Ok**

• **From Add Custom Tab** --> **Under General Group** --> Click --> **Custom Column**

• New Column Name --> **Vendor_Number**

• Custom Column Formula -->

```
=Table.Column([All],"VendorNumber")
```

• Press **Ok**

• Then Extract The Values From The **Vendor_Number** Column By Pressing The Dropdown and Click **Extract Values**

• Select **Delimiter** as your choice ( I took comma )

• Remove the column that not required and from **Home Tab** press **Close & Load Drop down**, from **Import Data** choose either **Existing sheet or New Sheet** and press **Ok**

Here is the `M-Code`

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Partnertbl"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"PartnerNumber"}, {{"All", each _, type table [PartnerNumber=number, VendorNumber=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Vendor_Number", each Table.Column([All],"VendorNumber")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Vendor_Number", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"All"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

### Approach Three

Using Excel Formulas applicable To **O365 & Excel 2021**

• Formula used in cell **D10**

```
=UNIQUE(Partnertbl[PartnerNumber])
```

• Formula used in cell **E10**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(Partnertbl[VendorNumber],D10=Partnertbl[PartnerNumber]))
```

[image: 3X_SOLUTIONS]

### Approach Four --> **Office 365 & Excel 2021 Formula**

• Formula used in cell **A10**

```
=LET(U,UNIQUE(A2:A5),
CHOOSE({1,2},U,BYROW(U,LAMBDA(A,
TEXTJOIN(", ",,(FILTER(B2:B5,A2:A5=A)))))))
```

[image: USING_LET_LAMBDA]